# Remove index.php in codeigniter 2.1.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried everything on google related to removing index.php from URL in codeigniter but no solution worked for me 
I am using codeigniter version 2.1.0
How I can remove index form my URL ?

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are you using apache? do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Have you read the basic documentation?

Comment: yes i read the whole documentation i m using apache and i also enabled mod_rewrite

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `application/config.php` make sure that

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Then set this as your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

You're all set!

Comment: there are different htaccess files in which one i should paste this code?

Comment: it redirects me to my localhost now

Comment: Change the RewriteBase to whatever path your project is set to. Also, this .htaccess file should go in the project's root folder where the "application" and "system" folders are.

Comment: My project is in C://wamp/www/mediabox
in media box i have application and system folders
wat should i write in the RewriteBase ?

Comment: Thanks everyone Its done i just replaced the RewriteBase to my project root 
thanks a lot

Comment: Or rather than removing access in your htaccess file, just put application and system outside of webroot...

Answer (score 5):

For me, Raphael Caixetas solution didn't work, but this did :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Didn't work for me at first. Then I figured out that you have to enable `mod_rewrite` in Apaches `httpd.conf` for it to work. Works perfectly now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

i tested this on apache2 on many different hosting and it works great.

use this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

be sure you have `enabled mod_rewirte` with a `phpinfo();`

then do this in config/config.php:

```
$config['index_page']   = '';
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

if it doesn't works yet, try to change the `$config['uri_protocol']='AUTO'` to one of the listed inside `application/config/config.php` file on line 40/54:

sometimes i used : `REQUEST_URI` instead of `AUTO` or `"QUERY_STRING"` for goDaddy hostings

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the example given in the CodeIgniter user guide?

> By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:
>
> ```
> example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
> ```
>
> You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some
>   simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative"
>   method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
> ```
>
> In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php,
>   images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php
>   file.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 1):

check your httpd.conf file

change

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: This worked for me. I am on CentOS 7.
I edited my "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" file under "<Directory "/var/www/html">"

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the .htaccess file given by Robert Stanley (see his answer), go to `application/config/config.php`, look for `$config['index_page'] = "index.php";` and replace it with `$config['index_page'] = ""`;

Comment: if my project is in C://wamp/www/myproject what path should I write for RewriteBase ?

Comment: In your root folder (the sams for index.php), which means: C://wamp/www/myproject

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use and works.
Use this code in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* website/index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Just make sure the .htaccess is in your root folder. (ie: xampp/htdocs)

Then in your config.php(application\config) replace 
`config['index_page']='index.php'` 
  to 
`config['index_page']=''`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change de config file!

**application/config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create .htaccess file in project folder and write:
   
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
 </IfModule>

 And You don't need to define in base_url in config file:
 $config['base_url'] = '';// blank it.

 I hope it will work perfectly ...
```