# How to remove index.php from a URL from CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url, localhost

I am new to [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter). I have an [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) server on Windows 8. Everything is fine, but the problem is about my URL, it doesn't look friendly. It looks like `localhost/ci/index.php/site/home` (where `ci` is my root folder for CodeIgniter). I want to make the URL more clean, like  `localhost/ci/home`, how can I do it?

My CodeIgniter version is 2.1.2.

I have done some research already, but in most of the cases it says to change the `.htaccess` file of CodeIgniter. But I have nothing in the `.htaccess` file; it's empty, except the line "Deny from all".

Comment: I am not understanding your problem.  You think your `.htaccess` file should remain empty despite what the documentation exactly tells you to put in there.  Solution:  snap out of it, RTM and follow the instructions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove index.php in codeigniter 2.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667226/remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-2-1-0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, in `config/config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //you can also leave blank this CI tend to find this by himself
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And try the following `.htaccess`. I use it for many sites, and it satisfies me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If it is not working yet, use a `phpinfo();` and check if mod_rewrite is `enabled`. If it is not enabled, you can follow the instructions in Stack Overflow question *[How do you enable mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131236)* to enable that.

If it is not working yet and mod_rewrite is `enabled` yet, you can try to switch these in `config/config.php`:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; //If not working, try one of these:
     'PATH_INFO'        Uses the PATH_INFO
    | 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
    | 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
    | 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace "Deny from all" with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the official documentation, *[CodeIgniter URLs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)*:

> You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine on<br>
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]<br>
```

Also if you are using Apache place .htaccess file in your root web directory. For more information, look in *[Codeigniter .htaccess](http://snipplr.com/view/5966/codeigniter-htaccess/)*.