# How to change url by name instead of id

Tags: php, codeigniter

in basic i have a table category like

```
|id|name    |
|1 |home    |
|2 |tutorial|
...
```

and table posts like

```
|id|name           |cateID|
...
|5 |getting started|2
...
```

**1. if i view(click) `tutorial` in category, then url will be like**

```
`index.php/nameOfControllerFile/functionName/2`
```

`2` is id of table category .

But i see all of website i view. it look like

```
category/tutorials.htm or like category/tutorials/
```

**2. and if i view `getting started` Post, then url will be like**

```
index.php/nameOfControllerFile/functionName/5
```

`5` is id of table posts.

But i see all of website i view. it look like

```
category/tutorials/getting-started.htm
```

Here is website like struction http://line25.com/category/tutorials

How can i change basic url to url like above ?

**Edit**

What is heppend if has two posts is the same title like

```
|id|name           |cateID|
...
|5 |getting started|2
|8 |getting started|2 
...
```

Comment: .HTACCESS will help you to rewrite the URL

Comment: You should clarify the question, if it really is how to use name instead of id then it's pretty simple, query for name instead if id...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Codeigniter's help docs on this found here:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

See the section named **Removing the index.php file**

Answer (score 0):

It's done via `.htaccess` file in apache server, re-writing the url ([mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)), for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

Above line will look for a file with `.php` extension when you give a url with `.html`, it means, if you write `home.html` in the address bar then the server will look for the `home.php` file and will launch it. Check [this](http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/) and [this one too](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/).

Also, for `CodeIgniter`, you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667226/remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-2-1-0).

Answer (score 0):

.HTACCESS will help you to rewrite the URL But you have to change route file in config according to your .HTACCESS file.

Answer (score 0):

No clue what you are asking. Might be routes. Check it:

Say you have a controller called `tutorials`. In that controller you have a `view` function to view a specific tutorial, and an `index` function for the tutorials homepage where you can see all of the tutorials as in the line25 link you showed.

**NOTE:** see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9667306/183254, https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+codeigniter+remove+index.php, other answers in this question, etc. to learn how to remove index.php from the url. The rest of this answer will assume you have that part figured out (no index.php in url).

so:

```
class Tutorials extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        //view all tutorials
    }

    function view($tutorial_identifier){
        //view single tutorial based on $tutorial_identifier
        //which can be either an id or a name
    }
}
```

would get you url's like

```
http://www.example.com/tutorials/view/5
```

to view a single tutorial, and

```
http://www.example.com/tutorials/
```

to view all tutorials.

IMPORTANT READING: [routes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

If you want the url to look more like

```
http://www.example.com/tutorials/5
```

for tutorial # 5, you can use a route like

```
$route['tutorials/(:num)'] = "tutorials/view/$1";
```

if you want it to look more like

```
http://example.com/tutorials/getting-started
```

you can add a route like

```
$route['tutorials/(:any)'] = "tutorials/view/$1";
```

and change the logic in the `view` function of your controller to look up the tutorial by the `name` rather than by the `id`.

Comment: But i fail in first step that is remove index.php in url. the first i try to remove index.php from url but it's not working. my struction look like `http://s11.postimg.org/pijy1qpf7/Capture.jpg` And in config.php in `application\config\` i do $config['index_page'] = '';. But not working ?

Comment: You need to use .htaccess as described in the links I posted and as posted IN OTHER ANSWERS IN THIS POST. Please do your research. Don't be lazy.