# how to remove index.php file from url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to remove index.php from my url, but I am confused which code i used in `.htaccess` file and what changes I have to make on related file in codeigniter .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove index.php in codeigniter 2.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667226/remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-2-1-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Taken from [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add just this line to your htaccess file  :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]    
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS, try [importing these rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ee215194(v=ws.10).aspx) to your web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">*
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^system.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^application.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```