# Index.php remove from url is not working in CI 3

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have tried a lot to remove index.php from the url .
Its not working at all.

In config.php

```html
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Then put this below code in .htaccess of my project root.

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

I have tried ,its throwing page not found errors only.
 [image]

[image]

[image]
Any suggestion ??
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove index.php in codeigniter 2.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667226/remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-2-1-0)

Comment: .htaccess RewriteBase /cloud

Comment: @James Lalor  ,thank you a lot you made my work .
Thank you is not enough for you .
:) :)

Comment: @sradha Wrote an answer, please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base URL is not the base domain name, so modify your .htaccess file and add the following:

```
RewriteBase /cloud
```

This should fix your issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `config.php` and `.htaccess` file.

Changes in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = ""; // And Remove index.php
```

Changes in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Make Sure**

1. Your `.htaccess` must under `cloud` directory.
2. Rewrite module must be enabled in Apache.

Comment: http://localhost/cloud/index.php/dashboard/index

Its in local host ..i canot show you .
I want to remove index.php 

The link should be .

http://localhost/cloud/dashboard/index

Comment: @sradha please check in `application/config/routes.php` default_controller should be `$route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard';`

Comment: But my default controller is login ,first login page will come so i gave login

Comment: @sradha is login is working without `index.php` in url?

Comment: Yes if i am giving http://localhost/cloud/

Login page is coming .

As i have mentioned $route['default_controller'] = 'Login';

Comment: after logout this one is coming .
http://localhost/cloud/index.php/login

Comment: @sradha http://localhost/cloud/login  is working, It means you rewrite is working ....

Comment: @sradha what is `base_url` in `config.php`?

Comment: @sradhaI have update my answer. Please make sure points in my answer

Comment: Your .htaccess must under cloud directory.
Rewrite module must be enabled in Apache.

This two is fine here...

Answer (score 0):

try this ,
Changes in `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your RewriteEngine is on in apache conf file if not then follow this link

[How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)